# Wiring a Micro-USB cable that doesn't have a black GND and has 3 unshielded wires?

Tags: usb, ground, wire, pinout

I have this Micro-USB cable I am trying to attach to a new Micro-USB connector, but I don't know how I can wire it when it is missing a GND and has these additional wires. I assume the unshielded wires are all S-GND? But why wouldn't they be a single wire in that case?

Any ideas?

[image: Wires]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting on a new connector is generally not worthwhile - even if you get the connectivity correct, it is hard to do it in a way that will be durable and lasting.

If you really want to do it though, the *only* truly reliable method for figuring out your puzzle is to go a continuity test from the intact end of the cable - eg, plug that end into USB socket, get a credible reference of the USB pinout, and figure out which signal is which.

If the other end is not standard USB (eg, unique product connector) you might have to do the test with the remains of the cut off end.  Generally though a non-standard cable would have its non-standardness on the end you are trying to replace, and the remaining end would be a standard USB "A" plug.

Don't trust the colors, they've been known to be wrong in manufactured cables - there's no real expectation that anyone would ever cut a manufactured cable and try to join it to something else.

Comment: The pinouts looked simple enough so I assumed it would be easy but I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The thick red wire is of course where the current is going thru cause it's thick.
Why else would that wire be so thick?

the white and green are for data cause they are thin , and the other 2 are ground.

I don't know why people feel the need to use continuity tests, use common sense , that wiring is pretty standard.

There is no way that is wrong , colors confirm that assumption .
Maybe in 2020 common sense died.

Comment: Once I got a batch of cables that were wired wrong. GND and VBUS were swapped. I mean that when you plugged them in, host VBUS was connected to device GND and host GND was connected to device VBUS. We actually shipped some to customers. Very unfortunate. Compared to that, swapping green and white seems like no big deal. I mean, don't get me wrong, I think that, almost for sure, the cable will follow the color code like you say. But the underlying tone you have, that there is no way for the colors to ever be wrong, that tone is not justified.

Comment: Can we agree the red wire is the current just because of thickness + color.
Cause if that is not true we have bigger issues.

Comment: I will agree that it SHOULD be. I will agree that I would be surprised if it is not. I wouldn't bet against it. But I still agree with the old original answer that it would be best to "Ohm it out" before going to the trouble of re-terminating it.

Comment: The original answer triggered me cause he discouraged the guy from following a simple project which could have led him to having a passion for it.
Let the guy try don't tell him all the things that could go wrong and how it's not worth it etc. The underlying negativity really annoyed me. Encourage someone to try something and try to be helpful dont say things like "Putting on a new connector is generally not worthwhile "  also he didn't actually answer the question, instead he took him on a detour about the other wires ,

Comment: I see your point, and what's more, I appreciate you sharing your perspective. For a lot of us I guess we view our job as trying to avoid problems and so we tend to list all the things that could go wrong. I can see how this sounds like negativity and could turn people off. I do try to stay positive unless someone is doing something that sounds like it just plane won't work.